# Closing crossposts

Tags: support, moderation

Back when the site were SharePointOverflow.com we would see alot of duplicate questions from SO.

This was one of the things i thought would get better when we moved to StackExchange, but even though we now have the possibility to vote to close as duplicate, it doesent consider a post on SO a valid entry. Is there a way to set this up, or is it a question about having more rep/being a mod?

Comment: Or to meybe "merge" them somehow...

Comment: Yeah as a workaround maybe just add a comment with a link and then close? I'd prefer to close the question on SO, and add a comment w/ link to dupe on SharePoint.SE

Comment: I just do not think they will allow us to move all SO content, and on other hand SP Pros cannot track all these different SE sites... :((((

Comment: @Toni It's possible for a Stack Overflow ♦ to migrate the question, then a corresponding SharePoint ♦ (so... Alex Angas) to merge the migration into the existing one. However, this should only be done for new questions, and if there is useful content to transfer (i.e. answers that aren't on the SharePoint copy). In the absense of such, closing with a comment like Kit suggests is probably a wise move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stack Exchange Network doesn't have the concept of cross posting between sites. The work flow right now is to migrate the question to the most appropriate site. That leaves the question on the *original* site closed (so it can be found through the link but not added to). The cross-posted content links to the "live" version where the active thread will be housed.

But those migration paths won't be defined for SharePoint Overflow until the site is out of public beta. If there is dire need, a moderator can move a post, but this should be used very sparingly. We don't want to rush into shuffling posts around the network until the site has a chance to become established and graduates.